# Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting ( in nested IF/ELSE IF statement

Tags: mysql

```
if v_test_id IS NOT NULL AND exists (select test_id from physicians where test_id =     v_test_id) then
    select 'phys_id' = -1;

elseif 
    if v_addl_language1 = '' THEN SELECT v_addl_language1 = NULL;
    if v_addl_language2 = '' THEN SELECT v_addl_language2 = NULL;
    if v_addl_language3 = '' THEN SELECT v_addl_language3 = NULL;
```

The error is occuring at if v_addl_language1...

I've tooled with adding parentheticals around the parameter of the if statements but that doesn't seem to fix it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You miss END IF; statement for every IF

The sintaxe is IF expression THEN commands; ELSEIF anotherExpression THEN commands; ELSE commands; END IF;

So your code at the `elseif` part should be:

```
ELSEIF someexpression THEN
   if v_addl_language1 = '' THEN SELECT v_addl_language1 = NULL; end if;
   if v_addl_language2 = '' THEN SELECT v_addl_language2 = NULL; end if;
   if v_addl_language3 = '' THEN SELECT v_addl_language3 = NULL; end if;
END IF;
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't do it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I tried adding one additionally at the end of the IF preceding the ELSEIF but that didn't work either

Comment: No, I think you missundertood me. The sintaxe is `IF expression THEN commands; ELSEIF anotherExpression THEN commands; ELSE commands; END IF; ` if you put an end if after the elseif it means that you left a elseif without an expression and without and IF before if. I will change my answer.